# Sorting json response in different javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, angular

**Using Angular2**

I get json response with a list of actions/moves.

- If the action type is `move`, assign it to movesForward array;
- If the action type is `fight`, assign it to actions array;

  `public movesForward = [];`
  `public actions = [];`

  ```
     ngOnInit()
     {
        this.userData.actions.forEach(function(entry) {
              switch(entry.type)
              {
                  case "move":
                  this.movesForward.push(entry);
                  break;
                  case "fight":
                  this.actions.push(entry);
                  break;
              }
          });
     }
  ```

  My problem is that the `foreach` is inside inner function and I can't access my public variables in this function.

  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'movesBack' of undefined`
- I'm not interested in using pipes since its one-time use only in one component.

How I can access my main class variables inside my foreach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `()=>` instead of `function()` (if you are using TS or ES6)

```
 ngOnInit()
   {
      this.JwtService.userData.zone.actions.forEach((entry) => {
            switch(entry.type)
            {
                case "move":
                this.movesForward.push(entry);
                break;
                case "fight":
                this.actions.push(entry);
                break;
            }
        });
   }
```

or in ES5

```
 ngOnInit()
   {
      this.JwtService.userData.zone.actions.forEach((function (entry){
            switch(entry.type)
            {
                case "move":
                this.movesForward.push(entry);
                break;
                case "fight":
                this.actions.push(entry);
                break;
            }).bind(this)
        });
   }
```

Comment: Right. An alternative solution is to use `.bind(this)`.